# How to Display if This Profile is Yours?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a basic profile page, which each URL for Users would apear as:

```
profile?username=Joe.Bills
```

However I Would like to know how to display if that profile is yours or not when you are on a profile. I have tried this but this did not work:

```
<?php if($uprofile['user_name'] && $_SESSION['user_name']){ echo "Your Profile";

} else { echo "Not Your Profile"; } 

?>
```

I know its using MySQL, and I Should go to PDO but this is only for small use.

This is how the profile info is input:

```
<?php

$name = $_REQUEST['username'];

$profile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$name'");
$uprofile = mysql_fetch_assoc($profile);
$username = $uprofile['user_name'];
$full = $uprofile['full_name'];
$image = $uprofile['image'];


?>
```

Comment: `if(something == 'xxx')` you're presently doing it wrong while using `isset()` - `!empty()`.

Comment: `if($uprofile['user_name'] === 'Joe.Bills' && $_SESSION['user_name'] === 'Joe.Bills') { //do something}` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- sight, just couple of second :D

Comment: @HendraNucleo hehe, yeah.. well mine was *in a nutshell*. Yours depicts the actual syntax they should use ;-)

Comment: Thing is, I want the same to be for every user, and if i put 'Joe.Bills' then only I can display my own profile?

Comment: that will depend on your query then and using a WHERE clause. Your question's a bit unclear right now. @JoeBills while using a GET array for `?username`

Comment: basicly, i need the profile's username, to match the session username, and if they both match, then display "Your Profile", else display "Not Your Profile"

Comment: @Fred-ii- My mistake, edited :D

Comment: If your `$_SESSION['usr_name']` had value, compare it using `$_GET` like mentioned by @Fred-ii- above. Example `<?php if($_GET['username'] === $_SESSION['user_name']) {//do something}`

Comment: I have edited above, how i get the profile data and how it is input, the profiles does work, iv'e tested, it gets each users data.

Comment: Here some useful link about `$_GET` and comparison operator http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php & http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Also read up on sessions http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp I'd of given you a link to PHP.net's reference, but given the experience, the official manuals can be a bit tough to understand at first.

Comment: Thank You, But how should I correct my PHP Statment to make it work though?

Comment: Now i asking you back, how you create link for  `profile?username=Joe.Bills`? Dynamically from database ? if yes, how it can be wrong agains `$_SESSION`?

Comment: @HendraNucleo I don't follow, What do you mean?

Comment: How you created this `http://someurl/profile?username=Joe.Bills`

Comment: my lines are in the original post. i have posted how i use it to get that.

Comment: Ok, i will put answer with complete example code.

Comment: Do not use mysql_, it's deprecated and has been deprecated for a long time now. Use mysqli_ or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following.

```
<?php 

if($_GET['username'] === $_SESSION['user_name']) { 
  echo "Your Profile";
} else { 
  echo "Not Your Profile"; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: [why did you steal this from comments...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893790/how-to-display-if-this-profile-is-yours#comment61352162_36893790)?? you practically did.

Comment: How he compare with the url query? example if url has query `/username?=Joe.Bills` meanwhile `$_SESSION['user_name'] = 'Mark_Never_Done` ?

Comment: well that bit them back eh @HendraNucleo ? gee, I wonder why.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Im on FM16 now and just lost Super Cup, FYI only sir hahahaha, off topic happines :D

Comment: He can get value from URL using $_GET or $_REQUEST global variable. for example `$_SESSION['user_name'] = $_GET['username']`

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad This changed it to "Your Profile" but every time I go to someone else's profile, it also states it "Your Profile", Even though its not.

Comment: @Joe Bill, i think i dint get your question properly. What i understand you are checking whether visiting profile page is for logged in user or not .... am i correct ?

Comment: basiclly, each user has their profile, and when you are logged in, if you are viewing your own profile, will display "this is your profile", however, if you view someone else's profile, it will display "This is not your profile".

Comment: Thats simple Joe .. you must be saving logged in user's username in session at the time of login, so you can compare logged in username with the username in URL .. that is i posted in my answer.

Comment: But how would i do that then? as i tried your method above and it just showed that it was my profile, on every profile

Comment: Mayday, mayday @Fred-ii- ? around now ?